# Is is possible to add in more information retrieved after a Lookupset call in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 2 datasets from which I populate my report, ActiveProjects (primary dataset) & ActiveTasks. I use the expression:

```
=Join(lookUpset(Fields!Title.Value, Fields!Related_Project.Value, "<a href = " & Chr(34) & "https://example" & Fields!ID.Value & Chr(34) & ">" & Fields!Title.Value & "</a>", "TeamTasks"), "<br> <br>")
```

This works great for retrieving each task grouped with its related project and it also includes a dynamic URL to the respective tasks.

My question is: Is it possible to include additional pieces of information (such as TargetDate - which is in the ActiveTasks Dataset) to be placed alongside the Task in the same Column & Row (Otherwise it wont remain aligned as the Task list goes on, since they are of varying length, while the date is not) ?

Ideally, it would return something like this:

```
Project Title    Task Title
_______________|_________________
   Project A   | Task a  12/12/16
               | Task b  02/12/16
               | Task c  28/11/16
   Project B   | Task a  22/11/16
               |
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this has been addressed before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=Join(
  lookUpset(
    Fields!Title.Value, Fields!Related_Project.Value,
    "<a href = " & Chr(34) & "https://example" & Fields!ID.Value & Chr(34) &
    ">" & Fields!Title.Value & "</a>" & " " & Fields!TargetDate.Value , "TeamTasks"
  ),
  "<br> <br>"
)
```

Also you may want to format your date, so you can use `FORMAT(Fields!TargetDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")` inside a LookupSet function.

It is not tested but should work.

Let me know if this helps.